# How does the low quality review queue work?

Tags: support, review, low-quality

I saw an [answer](https://serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts/202965) show up in the low quality queue [twice](https://serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts/203014).

Each time there was a majority of persons voting *Recommend Deletion*.

What would be the reason for a question to show up in that queue again almost immediately after the first review was completed?

And what is the actual effect of a majority of users voting *Recommend Deletion*, since it clearly didn't trigger a deletion?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work